# Filter by text not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I found this example [how to search in a list box](http://jsbin.com/egogeh/1/edit) on the web. It sounds very good but it's not working in IE. Any idea what to change in the code to make it work in IE?

when i start typing in the text box all the values of the list box just disappear.

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);
    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
      var search = $(this).val().trim();
      var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
      if (selectSingleMatch === true && $(select).children().length === 1) {
        $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
      }
    });            
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('#select').filterByText($('#textbox'), true);
});
```

Comment: When something doesn't work in a specific browser, always check for exceptions in the debug console.  In this case, trim was missing from IE's JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var search = $(this).val().trim();
```

to this:

```
var search = $.trim($(this).val());
```

Comment: Thanks!! (for editing also...)